# Need Clarification - JNLP file update in server

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I've created a JNLP file and placed in the server.It's working fine now.

My idea is - If someone was accessing the jnlp file from  some locations,i cannot update the supported jar files..

In that case, how will one update the jar files... ?

Comment: I do not understand the 2nd paragraph.  Why can you not update the Jar files?

Comment: As you know, the jnlp file will be calling main jar file while running.If suppose anyone was running the jnlp(jar) file in any client location ,it is possible to modify the jar in server-side...?.

Comment: *"..,it is possible to modify the jar in server-side...?"*  Yes, but normally the client computer would not *check* for a new Jar while the app. is running.  That is unless the options in the JNLP specify to load new Jars after launching the app., but even then, it would tend to check as soon as the app. is on-screen - once per application start.  OTOH, you might use the download service of the JNLP API to check for new Jars at intervals.  None of this prevents you from uploading new archives whenever is appropriate.  The server Jars are in no way 'locked' by the client.

Comment: Do my comments answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Thompson for your comment.

One can update the jar file on server irrespective if some-one was using your jnlp file or not..

Once you're uploaded the new jar file, the users who were accessing jnlp file will get updated immediately,when the jnlp file is started in their machine.

Comment: I wouldn't say either of those is true, and neither of them follows from @AndrewThompson's comments. For updating the JAR file at the server you would want to use an atomic move or rename so that downloads in progress weren't affected. For client updating, it isn't 'immediate', it is next time the client checks for updates, which is configurable.